# Whats the difference between axios and axios-es6 npm packages?

Tags: javascript, npm, vuejs2, axios

I'm new to npm and new to axios.  I'm looking to use axios in my next Vue2 based project to try it out but I'm unclear which axios to install.

axios: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios
axios-es6: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-es6

I've googled around to find the difference between axios and axios-ex6 and not found much.  Maybe it's too basic of a question.  Is the difference that axios-ex6 requires an ex6 shim to run on older browsers but axios does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both axios are same . Which ever you try it's not affect your code. It'll work same.

Small difference is axios es6 allow you to use new features of es6 that axios not allow.

Example In axios if you want to write function .

```
Function () { code will go here .... }
```

Example in axios es6

```
() => { Code will go here ... }
```

Both will give you same result but if you will use es6 you can get advantage of new syntax. And I'll recommend you to check es6 because it has so many advantages to use.

If you want to know more about es6 you can refer [this](http://es6-features.org) link.

Answer (score 0):

I think axios and axios-es6 are the same npm package use two name, they have the same github Address. Look...

￼￼￼[axios-es6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmfB1.jpg)